# How to refine stored procefure query results for age

Tags: stored-procedures

I'm trying to only display the results of people of age 20 and above, how would i do this? I've got code that displays the age:
 I've tried to use if statements but not quite sure where to place it.

```
select idstaff, name, date_of_birth,
  date_format(curdate(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') - 
  (date_format(curdate(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(date_of_birth, '00-%m-%d')) as age
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select idstaff, name, date_of_birth,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) as age
FROM your_table
WHERE
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) >= 20
```

`TIMESTAMDIFF(YEAR,date_of_birth,CURDATE())` calculates number of years (hence age) and you don't need an IF -- just include it as a WHERE clause: **to only display the results of people of age 20 and above**.